# Add custom attributes to link in Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor, links

Is it possible to add custom attributes to link in Gutenberg editor? Please don't tell me to add those attributes from **Edit as HTML** view. Probably, there can add a new field in the link editor popup for adding the new attributes.

Is it possible to add a new field in the Gutenberg link editor popup? See the link editor below.
[image]

Comment: (frustratingly), it's not yet possible: there's an open issue for this at https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/11599

Comment: Yeah this is something I am looking for as well.